# Grid view row updating does not get new entered values

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have used below code for `GridViewRowUpdating`, but after click on update button, it takes old values.
I checked by break point for `GridViewRowIpdating`, and all the text boxes have old values. And new entered values do not grab.

I tried a lot in google but I could not solve the problem.

```
protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

        int _Docid = (int)GridViewDocuments_Search.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        TextBox DocumentNo = (TextBox)GridViewDocuments_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DocumentNo");

        TextBox title = (TextBox)GridViewDocuments_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("title");
        TextBox unit = (TextBox)GridViewDocuments_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("unit");

        TextBox originator = (TextBox)GridViewDocuments_Search.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("originator");

        _DataContext.updateDoc(_Docid, DocumentNo.Text, title.Text, unit.Text, originator.Text);
        _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
        GridViewDocuments_Search.EditIndex = -1;


        var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);

         GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
        GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
    }

protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    //var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);
   // GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
    GridViewDocuments_Search.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
        var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);
        GridViewDocuments.Visible = false;
        GridViewDocuments_Search.Visible = true;
        GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
        GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();


}
```

Grid view marks up:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewDocuments_Search" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns=False 
          Visible="False" onrowcommand="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowDeleting" 
  DataKeyNames="DocID" PageSize="100" 
          onrowcancelingedit="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCancelingEdit" 
          onrowediting="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowEditing" 
          onrowupdating="GridViewDocuments_Search_RowUpdating"  >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Details">
           <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID ="btn_Show" Text="Details" runat= "server" CommandName= "Details" CommandArgument='<%#
        Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DocNo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DocumentNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentNo") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="title">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="title" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>





        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DocID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DocID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Originator">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Originator" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Originator") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Originator") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Unit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Unit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Unit") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>





        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand

```
protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

    int _Docid = (int)GridViewDocuments_Search.DataKeys[rowindex].Value;

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Details":
            Response.Redirect("~/Documentfortest.aspx?DocID=" + _Docid);
            break;
        case "Delete":
            _DataContext.DeleteDoc(_Docid);
            _DataContext.SubmitChanges();

            break;

    }

    var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);

    GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
    GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
    //UpdatePanel1.Update();

}
```

Comment: Where are you binding your gridview initially?

Comment: my gridview will be bebinding after clicking on search button and in the page_load i do not have  any code

Comment: can you post your rowcommand event code?

Comment: i added rowcommand event

Comment: I think you need to move your databind code in `rowcommand` under `Case "Delete"` before `break;`, you are rebinding your `gridview` in `rowcommand` for every command that is fired (edit/update).

Comment: for more information in my page i have 2 gridviews, first one will be populate when run the page by linqdatasource and it's datasource is a table. and secound one will be visible and populate after pressing search button and first gridview  will be hide.

thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot,after 3 days and question in many site forums you solved my problem. it works perfectly.

Comment: i posted my comment as answer below, you can mark my answer below as answer to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move your databind code in rowcommand under Case "Delete" before break;, you are rebinding your gridview in rowcommand for every command that is fired (edit/update).

For example:

```
protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowCommand
(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

    int _Docid = (int)GridViewDocuments_Search.DataKeys[rowindex].Value;

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Details":
            Response.Redirect("~/Documentfortest.aspx?DocID=" + _Docid);
            break;
        case "Delete":
            _DataContext.DeleteDoc(_Docid);
            _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
             //rebind only if row is deleted
             var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);

             GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
             GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
             break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event fires **before** your data in updated in the grid. This allows you to make any changes to the data before it is updated.

The newly entered values are available to you in the collection [NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx).

This is how you could use it.

```
protected void GridViewDocuments_Search_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

        int _Docid = (int)GridViewDocuments_Search.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        _DataContext.updateDoc(_Docid, 
                        e.NewValues["DocumentNo"].ToString(), 
                        e.NewValues["title"].ToString(),
                        e.NewValues["unit"].ToString(),
                        e.NewValues["originator"].ToString());
        _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
        GridViewDocuments_Search.EditIndex = -1;

        var query = _DataContext.spQuickSearchDoc(txtSearchKeywords.Text);

         GridViewDocuments_Search.DataSource = query;
        GridViewDocuments_Search.DataBind();
}
```

Note: There is also a RowUpdated event that fires after the row is updated.

Comment: e.NewValues["DocumentNo"].ToString() is null

Comment: for more information in my page i have 2 gridviews, first one will be populate when run the page by linqdatasource and it's datasource is a table. and secound one will be visible and populate after pressing search button and first gridview  will be hide.

thanks.